# Assigning same base class to many library definitions

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

So I know you can assign a base class to a library definition within the Movieclips library information field but If I have 30 items in the library and I change the Base class this becomes a pain in the ass, can this be done programmatically when I instantiate the library definition? Cheers.

```
var new_shiz:MyItem1 = new MyItem1(); // Needs to have a generic base class of MyItem
```

Answer (score 1):

With Flash CS4 you can select multiple items in your library and set the base class for all of them (via right click, as usual). But sometimes you could really need more advanced way to automate something — then JSFL is your friend, and http://www.xjsfl.com/ will make your friendship happy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to grab them as their superclass? 
You can do this, if your library class is just a bunch of graphics:

```
var new_shiz:Sprite = new MyItem1() as Sprite;
```

or

```
var new_shiz:MovieClip = new MyItem1() as MovieClip;
```

Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi, more new MyItem1() as MyItem (which doesn't seem to work) so when I instantiate MyItem1 it will behave as defined in the MyItem class file, multiple library items will share the same behaviour

Comment: Are you trying to make them all extend the same class? Because you can choose a custom class as the Base Class. So you can have several different symbols that all extends your base Class. Just make sure you custom class extends an appropriate display object class for the symbol type.

Answer (score -3):

```
// SAVE THIS CODE AS:    WHATEVERNAMEYOULIKETOCALLIT.jsfl

// Now simply open flash, select the items you'd like to change the base class IN THE LIBRARY and double click the script



/**
 * ...
 * @author Bruno Pavanelli Mestre dos Magos
 */
var lib = fl.getDocumentDOM().library;
var libSelection = lib.getSelectedItems();
var length = libSelection.length;
var appendix;
var count = 0;

Validate();

function Validate()
{
    fl.outputPanel.clear();
    fl.trace(">>> Change Base Class Name\nThis will change the base class name to every\nselected item in your library.");

    if(length <= 0)
    {
        fl.trace("No objects selected in the library!");
        alert("No objects selected in the library!");
        return;
    }

    appendix = prompt("Choose a name for the base class(ex: flash.display.MovieClip)");
    if(appendix == null) 
    {
        fl.trace("Appendix selection canceled!");
        return;
    }

    Execute();
} 

function Execute()
{

    for(var itemIndex=0; itemIndex < length; itemIndex++)
    {
        var theItem = libSelection[itemIndex];
        if(theItem.linkageExportForAS)
            {
            theItem.linkageBaseClass = appendix;
            continue;
        }else{
            theItem.linkageExportForAS = true;
            var wholePackage = appendix.split('.');
            var name = wholePackage[wholePackage.length-1];
            theItem.linkageClassName = name + itemIndex.toString();
            theItem.linkageBaseClass = appendix;
        }
        count++;
    }

    fl.outputPanel.trace("Process Complete!\n" + count + " base class name(s) modified!");
}
```

Comment: Realy? -2? That perfectly answer his question.